# Auto Click Button on Launch of Modal

Tags: javascript, reactjs, button, onclick

I have a `button` in a modal that I would like to auto click once the modal is opened. I am running this on launch of modal, but it is not working for me.

```
const handleClick = () => {
   console.log('auto clicked');

};

const myBtnRef = useRef(null);
useEffect(() => {
   myBtnRef.current.addEventListener('click', handleClick);
   myBtnRef.current.click();
}, []);

<button ref={myBtnRef}> Auto Click Me </button>
```

I am currently getting this error `Object is possibly 'null'.ts(2531` on these 2 lines

```
myBtnRef.current.addEventListener('click', handleClick);
myBtnRef.current.click();
```

Any help would be appreciated and maybe this isn't the best way to accomplish this, open to suggestions.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because for some reason (your code is partial, so I can't say what's the exact reason), the component is not yet fully rendered.
So during that time, myBtnRef can be or is still null.
Try this,

```
useEffect(() => {
        myBtnRef?.current?.addEventListener('click', handleClick);
        myBtnRef?.current?.click();
    }, []);
```

If the above doesn't works, then you can try making it async.

```
useEffect(() => {
    setTimeout(()=> {
        myBtnRef?.current?.addEventListener('click', handleClick);
        myBtnRef?.current?.click();
    });
}, []);
```

Answer (score 0):

try this - Initialization of myBtnRef inside useEffect hook. You are trying to access current property myBtnRef object before value is assigned.

```
useEffect(() => {
   const myBtnRef = useRef(null);
   const handleClick = () => {
      console.log('Inside handleClick');
   };   
   myBtnRef.current.addEventListener('click', handleClick);
   myBtnRef.current.click();
}, []);
```

Comment: I still get the same error for `myBtnRef.current`

Comment: Use your code as it is only put this line 'const myBtnRef = useRef(null);' outside useEffect()

Comment: I still the same with that as well

Comment: Strange, maybe it is happening accessing myBtnRef.current outside the useEffect(). try this 
`const buttonRef = useRef(null);
const handleClick = () => {
    console.log('Inside handleClick');
};
useEffect(() => {
    const buttonElement = buttonRef.current;
   //your code
}, []);`

Comment: it is the `.click()` that it isn't liking

Comment: https://playcode.io/1511435
Check this link

Comment: I see that is working there. It is a TypeScript error I think. I added screenshot to my question above.

Comment: I added `const myBtnRef = useRef<any>(null);` and it mutes error. Going to debug some more